# Django - Como distinguir qual botão foi clicado?

Tags: html, django

Na template de pesquisa da minha aplicação eu tenho 3 tags `<button>`, uma para buscar, a outra para editar e outra para apagar:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" id="buscar" name="buscar">Buscar</button>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" id="editar" name="editar">Editar</button>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" id="apagar" name="apagar">Apagar</button>
```

Estando na mesma template, como eu faço para que o Django faça a distinção entre os `<buttons>`, para que dependendo do botão clicado a view correta seja executada ?!

Ex: Se eu clicar no botão deletar ele vai apagar o item que a pesquisa localizou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Que eu saiba, se você tem vários botões em um mesmo formulário não dá para submeter esse formulário a páginas diferentes a não ser que você use JavaScript para mudar o `action` do `form`. O que você pode fazer é ter uma view genérica que "roteie" a chamada para uma view diferente dependendo de qual botão foi clicado.

```python
def view_generica(request, *args, **kwargs):
    view_certa = None

    if request.GET['buscar']:
        view_certa = uma_view
    elif request.GET['editar']:
        view_certa = outra_view
    elif request.GET['apagar']:
        view_certa = terceira_view
    else
        return HttpResponse("Erro")

    return view_certa(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Nota: o código para tratar do botão específico que foi clicado veio [dessa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19761466/520779). Não testei, então não tenho como afirmar com certeza se funciona na prática.

Outra alternativa é usar links comuns (`a`) em vez de botões, e [estilizá-los para se parecerem com botões](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8357058/520779). Nesse caso, você tem de atribuir corretamente o `href` no seu template para carregar a view com os parâmetros certos (i.e. identificando o item localizado na sua busca).

Por fim, você pode criar um `form` diferente para cada botão, atribuindo o `action` de acordo. Se os dados retornados pelo seu template são imutáveis, pode ser uma boa opção. Cada `form` então repetiria os dados (identificação) do item retornado, em um *hidden input* por exemplo (de modo a ser enviado à view junto à submissão do formulário).